# Top navigation icon stays on left side

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

The mobile top navigation icon for my webpage appears on the left side of the screen (next to the logo) despite having the float right value. When I shrink my browser to tablet size, however, it appears in the upper right corner, where it should be.

Each link (including the nav icon) has this class:

```
.topnavLink {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: rgb(97, 198, 245);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
```

I've already tried removing the class from the icon and adding `float: right;` in the style. My goal is to keep it in the top right corner no matter what size the screen is (except for the desktop view, of course). If there's any other code you'd like to see, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your code completely or put it in one of the online editors to solve the problem sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: inline;`

```css
.txt{
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p class="txt">hello</p>
<p class="txt">world</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.topnavLink {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 display: block;
 color: rgb(97, 198, 245);
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

**the center alignment of the text will lead to little gap in right side if u want complete right u may as well align right.**
it would be better if you share the html as well there might be parent elements altering the alignment.